# MySQL TRUNCATE or ROUND with variable decimal length

Tags: mysql, variables, rounding, truncate

I am not able to TRUNCATE (or round) a decimal on **variable decimal lengh**.
Here's my MySQL query:

```
SELECT
TRUNCATE( `amount` , `decimal_length` ) AS truncated_decimal,
FROM table

-- sample data
amount    decimal length
123.123    0
456.456    1
789.789    2

--expected outcome
truncated_decimal
123
456.4
789.78

--current outcome (wrong)
truncated_decimal
123.123
456.456
789.789
```

My `truncated_decimal` variable is returned WITHOUT truncation, i.e. default decimal length from table. Same behavior with ROUND function.
Variable `decimal_length` is an integer that is different for different rows in table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please share example values you're passing, the result you're getting and the result you're trying to get for those values?

Comment: When i have the lengths in a second table and join.. it seems to work [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca57d2/1/0)

Comment: Added sample data.

Comment: xQbert  I am not able to open your sqlfiddle link, doesn't load data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the correct answer to get variable length decimals is to use **FORMAT** function:

```
SELECT
FORMAT( `amount` , `decimal_length` ) AS truncated_decimal,
FROM table
```

It does go with rounding, but at least you get needed **variable length decimals**.

Answer (score 0):

Use Trim to remove trailing zero's

```
SELECT 
TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM TRUNCATE( `amount` , `decimal_length` ))
FROM table
```

Comment: It's not always '0' at the end. And I need variable length of trimming.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Example with a field name
SELECT
ROUND( `field_name` , 2 ) AS truncated_decimal
FROM table

-- Example with just a number
SELECT
ROUND( '285,1234' , 2 ) AS truncated_decimal

==> 285,12
```

You mix up truncate function with round function

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I am not mixing - I want to truncate or round to variable decimal length.