# Passing a dynamic value to a mySQL function

Tags: mysql, variables, parameters, truncate

Say I have a table of values that I want to truncate to different places of decimals.

like tblmetrics below

```
+------+---------+---------+---- -------+
| id   | metric  | value   | places     |
+------+---------+---------+------------+
|    1 | salary  | 12.345  |     3      |
+------+---------+---------+------------+
|    2 |  age    | 25.000  |     0      |
+------+---------+---------+------------+
|    3 | height  | 124.100 |     1      |
+------+---------+---------+------------+
```

.

```
select id,metric truncate(value,places) from tblmetrics;
```

will result in

```
id,metric,value
1,salary,12.345
2,age,25.000
3,height,124.1000
```

i.e. no truncation. I'd like the values to be

id,metric,value
 
1,salary,12.345
2,age,25
3,height,124.1

If I declare a variable and use that as a parameter to truncate

Set @num_places=1;

...that won't work either.

However

Set @num_places='1';

... does work.

Any ideas how to use the built in functions with dynamic parameter values?

Comment: which datat type is the value column ..  ??

Comment: The value column is decimal.

Comment: Looks like the question was answered before but it didn't turn up in the previous searches I performed.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553161/mysql-truncate-or-round-with-variable-decimal-length